# Storefront registering an account: Domain is null

Tags: sxa-storefront

I am using the Storefront with SXA (XC 9.0.3) and get a `Domain is null` error when registering a new account (URI is `api/cxa/Account/Registration`):

```
{"Errors":["Registration: The Domain is null and is probably not defined in Domain Manager."],
"Info":[],
"Warnings":[],
"HasErrors":true,
"HasInfo":false,
"HasWarnings":false,
"Success":false,
"Url":null,
"ContentEncoding":null,
"ContentType":null,
"Data":null,
"JsonRequestBehavior":1,
"MaxJsonLength":null,
"RecursionLimit":null}
```

Where should I configure the domain value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't setup your security for your Tenant/Site, or if you have, the domain is not configured. If you setup your SXA Security and pick a new domain for the tenant or site, it is not automatically added to the `Domains.config` file.

To configure the domain, just click the **Domain Manager** from the `Launch Pad`:

[image]

Then click **New** and add the domain:

[image]

This will update the `/App_Config/Security/Domains.config` file, so you may need to deploy that out to your CD servers too.

Comment: That helps. Getting now a next error: `Invalid or missing value for property \u0027Domain\u0027.","User created but external Id was not provided."`. Followed https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/set-up-security-for-a-tenant-and-a-site.html but doesn't help.

Comment: Turned out I had to add the domain to the `Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Customers.CustomerPropertiesPolicy` in as well.